# Openmdao - compute finite difference in parallel when optimizing

Tags: openmdao

I have made a simple example (see below) which does the fd in serial. What is the best way to do this in parallel? I am using Python 3.6 and OpenMDAO 2.4.0.

```
   import numpy as np

   from openmdao.api import Problem, ScipyOptimizeDriver, ExecComp, IndepVarComp, ExplicitComponent, Group

   class WorkFlow(ExplicitComponent):
       def setup(self):
           self.add_input('x', np.ones(5))
           self.add_output('y', 2.0)
           self.declare_partials('y', 'x', method='fd')

       def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
           print('comm:', self.comm.rank, inputs['x'])
           print()
           outputs['y'] = abs(np.sum(inputs['x']**2) - 9)

   prob = Problem()
   indeps = prob.model.add_subsystem('indeps', IndepVarComp(), promotes=['*'])
   indeps.add_output('x', np.ones(5))

   prob.model.add_subsystem('wf', WorkFlow(),  promotes_inputs=['x'])

   prob.driver = ScipyOptimizeDriver()
   prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'
   prob.driver.options['tol'] = 1e-9

   prob.model.add_design_var('x', lower=-10.0, upper=10.0)

   prob.model.add_objective('wf.y')

   prob.setup()
   prob.run_driver()
   print(prob['x'])
   print(prob['wf.y'])
```

Answer (score 0):

As of OpenMDAO v2.4 you could not do parallel finite-difference. However, the feature has been recently added to the master branch of OpenMDAO and will be officially released in OpenMDAO V2.5 soon.

To use the feature right now, install the repository version of openMDAO (You can not do `pip install openmdao`. instead clone the repository from github and then `pip install -e <location of the cloned repo>`).

Then you can follow the instructions on the [documentation page](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/features/core_features/working_with_derivatives/parallel_fd.html) for parallel FD.

Here is your actual code though. The only change to the component is that when you instantiate it you provide the `num_par_fd=5` argument to the component. Then when you call the file, you should run it under mpi like this:

`mpiexec -n 5 python test.py`

Here is what test.py should look like:

```
   import numpy as np

   from openmdao.api import Problem, ScipyOptimizeDriver, ExecComp, IndepVarComp, ExplicitComponent, Group

   class WorkFlow(ExplicitComponent):
       def setup(self):
           self.add_input('x', np.ones(5))
           self.add_output('y', 2.0)
           self.declare_partials('y', 'x', method='fd')

       def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
           print('comm:', self.comm.rank, inputs['x'])
           print()
           outputs['y'] = abs(np.sum(inputs['x']**2) - 9)

   prob = Problem()
   indeps = prob.model.add_subsystem('indeps', IndepVarComp(), promotes=['*'])
   indeps.add_output('x', np.ones(5))

   prob.model.add_subsystem('wf', WorkFlow(num_par_fd=5),  promotes_inputs=['x'])

   prob.driver = ScipyOptimizeDriver()
   prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'
   prob.driver.options['tol'] = 1e-9

   prob.model.add_design_var('x', lower=-10.0, upper=10.0)

   prob.model.add_objective('wf.y')

   prob.setup()
   prob.run_driver()
   print(prob['x'])
   print(prob['wf.y'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Though I find it a bit turned up side down that the documentation of the feature is released before the actual feature?

Comment: I get an error though when I run the code above. `File "MPI/Comm.pyx", line 640, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Allgather (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:98562)
mpi4py.MPI.Exception: Invalid buffer pointer, error stack:
PMPI_Allgather(958): MPI_Allgather(sbuf=0x2b28250, scount=1, MPI_INT, rbuf=0x2b28250, rcount=1, MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
PMPI_Allgather(931): Buffers must not be aliased`. Do you have a clue? The code from the documentation of parallel FD runs fine...

Comment: Does anybody have an idea why the above code does not run?

Comment: The code above runs fine on my macbook.  Do you know if you're using openmpi?  The OpenMDAO MPI code has only been tested using openmpi.  I have a vague recollection of getting an error like this when using an older version of OpenMDAO with MPICH.